# Digital Right Management (DRM) forward lock in Windows Mobile

Tags: security, windows-ce, mobile-phones, drm

Is it possible to apply DRM forward lock to windows mobile applications?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

You need to use the Windows Mobile [File-Based Digital Rights Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms879882.aspx) API.  This is a WM5 API, so it's not supported under WM 2003.

Your device needs to have a FDRM provider installed.  I beleave most WM5/6 devices should have some sort of provider installed by default in the ROM.

Comment: Shane, does this include .dm wrapped files?

Comment: I'm not sure I can answer that question since I don't know what ".dm wrapped files" means.  The API is just a wrapper API around FDRM Providers.  The provider controls what drm "formats" it supports (e.g. OMA DRM V1.0 or OMA DRM v2.0).  I haven't used it enough to know what common providers use.